# Digital Oscilloscopes

Tags: oscilloscope

EDIT - I am happy with the comments to the first question, so I will replace it with a different question that I would like answers to. The 2 scopes in question are the Tektronix TBS1072B and the Rigol DS1054Z.

***The Tektronic has a CAT II 300Vrms input voltage safety rating.***

***The Rigol has a CAT I 300Vrms input voltage safety rating.***

I need to do some 240Vrms mains measurements and would like to know the difference between the safety rating categories mentioned above.

I'm assumming the tektronic is the much safer scope to use for mains probing due to the higher CAT safety rating?

But can the Rigol still be safely used for isolated mains measurements (DUT through an isolating transformer with ratio 1:1 or 10:1)?

Or should I be considering differential probes as well?

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: storage is also important. the rigol is the clear winner there millions of samples vs thousands on the tektronix.

Comment: @David: Your edit doesn't change the nature of the question from opinion based. Edit it to ask for an explanation of technical differences or features you are unsure of, weigh up the answers and *you* decide which is best for your requirements.

Comment: Which one is "better" depends on what you mean by "better". If 2 channels isn't enough for your general use then the Rigol is "better". If you need some option that the Tektronix has but the Rigol doesn't then the Tek. is "better". Anyone who thinks that 50 MHz vs 70 MHz is a major difference doesn't understand what that those numbers mean. Also, the Rigol has a software unlock to 100 MHz. What is "better" is opinion based unless you specify **exactly** what you need. For what you list, both Scopes will be equally fine.

Comment: This is off topic of course.  One thing to keep in mind about the Rigol is that the trigger is after the ADCs, so if you try to use it as 2 channels plus another signal as a trigger, you'll actually be operating the ADCs in 4 channel mode and get only a quarter of the sample rate, not half of it as you'd expect with only two analog channels being displayed.

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question but please be careful with the edits so that you don't render the comments that people took trouble to write as irrelevant.